# How to show track score as drum notation in Logic Pro?

Tags: midi, logic-pro, scoring

If I opened a midi on Logic Pro 9 and had a drum track, how can I show the track's score in drums notation? I have trouble finding any documentations for it online and I can't seem to actually change the style scheme for the track. It looks like a dropdown menu but doesn't drop down and double clicking it seems to open a style editor and any changes doesn't apply to the track.

Answer (score 4):

Thank you for asking this question, because I have been wondering about this myself. A few reputation points is all the motivation I need to actually go find out. :)

I managed to get drum notation by just successfully doing what you tried to. The magic trick is not to double click the style scheme for the track. Just click and hold, and a menu will appear. From there, you can choose #Drums.

However, you will find out that when you try to place a note in the score view, logic is behaving weird. While you click and hold to place a note, the note does not give the expected sound, given its position in the score. This seems to be true for all notes except some Toms. As soon as a note is placed though, it jumps to its expected position. This behavior makes it almost impossible to work with the score, even though it looks good when done. So I found this [pdf](http://samuelmorse.info/files/drum_set_logic.pdf) which explains how to make everything work as expected. It is for logic pro 8 but I tried it using logic pro 9, and it seems to work here as well.  Good Luck. :)